# Alternative route of transferring Xcode App to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

I would like to test my app on my iPhone to try out various features. I have purchased the developers program and everything is working fine unfortunetly my USB ports on my computer are been faulty and won't connect the iPhone  properly instead its connecting and disconnecting continuously anyways thats another story. is there any other way to connect and iPhone 4s rather than USB i heard  you used to be able to wirelessly but Xcode remove this on the updates

thanks in advance

Comment: What Mac have you got? Can't you get a 30pin dock connector -> FireWire? There is no way to debug an app without a physical connection to your mac unfortunately, all other alternatives would be using ADHoc Distribution builds

Comment: MacBookPro Retina  2013model and i have no idea just a standard genuine apple cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Testflight, https://www.testflightapp.com, compile the project and upload the IPA to their site, you can then download the app on your device via the Testflight link

Answer (score 0):

As @Flexicoder suggested Testflight can be used. But a quicker and faster way could be Diawi - http://www.diawi.com.

I have used it for sample projects and quick projects. You can read their security and privacy on their website.

EDIT: Can't post comments yet, therefore I post it as answer.

Comment: Deviks is actually answering the question... and it's not a link-only answer, he's pointing OP in the direction of a tool that does what OP asked.

Comment: I am answering OP's question. Thanks Gervasio.